# MacVim crash with Gundo

Tags: macos, vim, macvim

Every time I invoke gundo MacVim crashes with the following error.

```
Vim: Caught deadly signal SEGV
Vim: Finished.
```

It works fine in Normal vim but I am not sure what the problem is I built the app via macports and it is the latest version and I am using the latest version of Janus.

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Aug 13 2012 23:40:11)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-244, 246-390
Compiled by ley@appa
Huge version with MacVim GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+arabic +autocmd +balloon_eval +browse ++builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent +clientserver
+clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments +conceal +cryptv -cscope       +cursorbind
+cursorshape +dialog_con_gui +diff +digraphs +dnd -ebcdic +emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search
+farsi +file_in_path +find_in_path +float +folding -footer +fork() +fullscreen +gettext
-hangul_input +iconv +insert_expand +jumplist +keymap +langmap +libcall +linebreak +lispindent
+listcmds +localmap -lua +menu +mksession +modify_fname +mouse +mouseshape +mouse_dec -mouse_gpm
-mouse_jsbterm +mouse_netterm -mouse_sysmouse +mouse_xterm +mouse_urxvt +multi_byte +multi_lang
-mzscheme +netbeans_intg +odbeditor +path_extra +perl +persistent_undo +postscript +printer +profile
+python -python3 +quickfix +reltime +rightleft -ruby +scrollbind +signs +smartindent -sniff
+startuptime +statusline -sun_workshop +syntax +tag_binary +tag_old_static -tag_any_white +tcl
+terminfo +termresponse +textobjects +title +toolbar +transparency +user_commands +vertsplit
+virtualedit +visual +visualextra +viminfo +vreplace +wildignore +wildmenu +windows  +writebackup
-X11 -xfontset +xim -xsmp -xterm_clipboard -xterm_save
```

I have been having this problem with MacVim only. Vim is working fine.

Comment: Random ideas… Try with a genuine MacVim downloaded and installed manually. Start MacVim without a vimrc and without plugins. Install Gundo manually.

Comment: Gundo also requires MacVim to be compiled with Python and maybe the fact that your version isn't compiled with Python3 is the issue. The Homebrew version of MacVim does have Python/Python3 support compiled so that might be a next step as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using homebrew instead of MacPorts.

For those who are having this problem and are using homebrew, this worked for me:

```
brew unlink python
brew unlink macvim
brew remove macvim
brew install -v --force macvim
brew link macvim
brew link python
```

One-liner for copying and pasting into the terminal:

```
brew unlink python && brew unlink macvim && brew remove macvim && brew install -v --force macvim && brew link macvim && brew link python
```

(from https://code.google.com/p/macvim/issues/detail?id=392)